# Setting LaTeX => PS => PDF in RStudio

Tags: knitr, postscript, rstudio

I am using RStudio, with knitr, and want to use Lodewyckx's graphicalmodels.sty for graphs. It requires changing output profile to LaTeX to PS to PDF. Can this be done in RStudio still using knitr?

Comment: I do not think it is possible in RStudio (at least at the moment).